# Read/write var at the same time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

If we assume something like this in a web page :

```
<script>
  var yolo;
</script>

<script src="first.js"></script>
<script src="second.js"></script>
```

In first.js :

```
async function setvalue() {
   while (true) {
     yolo = Math.random();
   }
}
setvalue();
```

In second.js :

```
async function printvalue() {
   while (true) {
     var rdmnumber = yolo;
     console.log(rdmnumber);
   }
}
printvalue()
```

I know in many languages do something like this (or with thread) is dangerous; 
What about javascript ?
What's the best practice ?

Comment: What's the best practice for _what_ exactly? What is your end goal? Why do you have these infinite loops? Why are these `async` functions? You'll have to be way more specific to get any sensible answer here.

Comment: For use a variable that can be write or read potentialy at the same moment. Async func and infinite loop are only there to show the ability to write and read the "Yolo" variable at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For use a variable that can be write or read potentialy at the same moment

That isn't a situation you can have in JS.

> I know in many languages do something like this (or with thread) is dangerous; What about javascript ?

async functions aren't threads.

async functions don't make blocking code non-blocking. `printvalue` never gets called because `setvalue` never ends.

If `setvalue` ever did go to sleep (because it hit an `await` and waited for a promise) then `printvalue` would run … but it would never touch `yolo` at the same time as `setvalue` because `setvalue` would be asleep.

The JS event loop is only going to do **one thing** at a time.

The worst you are going to get is a race condition where the variable is accessed in an unexpected *order*.

Even if you used web workers, they wouldn't have access to each other's variables. They can only send and receive messages.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will never go past `setvalue`, as it will never end. If you want to do something like this, write your functions like this:

```
async function setvalue() {

   yolo = Math.random();
   setTimeout(setvalue);

}
```

```
async function printvalue() {

   var rdmnumber = yolo;
   console.log(rdmnumber);
   setTimeout(printvalue);

}
```

this will make sure your functions will not block the event loop.